# How to upload video with Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been struggling for weeks to get figure out how to upload video using the graph api. I've gone through all the documentation and i just don't understand what i must do to get a correct response from the graph api before i write the code. I've included an image.

Can someone just tell me like a child what I must put in exactly?

[image]

Comment: You need to send the actual video data as value of the `source` parameter – in the same format, as a file upload via an HTML form would send the data. If you are just sending a file name, the API of course doesn’t know what to do with that.

Comment: thanks for the info but I've tried adding file_url and a actually http link and the same thing happens. so i still don't understand.

Comment: @CBroe i figured it out. check solution below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to use graph api with c# for unity.

you can post a comment and post a video.
the url given is just an open video that was available, choose your own if you want, or if it becomes unavailable in the future.

enjoy!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;
using Facebook.MiniJSON;

public class FBVideoPost : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // this is to post string
        postStatus ();

        //this is to post video
        this.StartCoroutine(this.StartVideoUpload());
    }

    void postStatus()
    {
        var formdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        formdata.Add ("message", "This is my third post!");
        FB.API("/me/feed", HttpMethod.POST, delegate (IGraphResult callback){
            Debug.Log ("This is a test!");
        },formdata);
    }

    private IEnumerator StartVideoUpload()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        WWW www = new WWW("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
        while(!www.isDone) {
            yield return null;
            Debug.Log("progress : "+www.progress);
        }
        Debug.Log("size : "+www.size);
        var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
        wwwForm.AddBinaryData("file", www.bytes, "Video.MOV","multipart/form-data");
        wwwForm.AddField("title", "Hello World");
        wwwForm.AddField("description", "How you doing?");

        FB.API("me/videos", HttpMethod.POST, UploadFinish, wwwForm);
    }

    private void UploadFinish(IGraphResult result) {
        Debug.Log("result : "+result.ToString()+" , error : "+result.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post another forum thread where you answered yourself and that helped me in addition to your answer here.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1167534/how-to-send-file-local-path-using-wwwform-on-ios-a.html

---

In short, for anyone looking to "Upload Videos using the FB SDK from iOS", follow Luke's answer and add the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;
using Facebook.MiniJSON;

public class FBVideoPost : MonoBehaviour {

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {

    // this is to post string
    postStatus ();

    //this is to post video
    this.StartCoroutine(this.StartVideoUpload());
}

 void postStatus()
 {
    var formdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    formdata.Add ("message", "This is my third post!");
    FB.API("/me/feed", HttpMethod.POST, delegate (IGraphResult callback){
        Debug.Log ("This is a test!");
    },formdata);
 }

 private IEnumerator StartVideoUpload()
 {
     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

     ///ADD THIS 

     //this is the path to your file.          
     String VideoLocStr = Application.persistentDataPath + "Your_Video.mov"
     String pathForIOS = VideoLocStr.Replace (" ","%20");
     WWW www = new WWW(pathForIOS);

     ///

     while(!www.isDone) {
        yield return null;
        Debug.Log("progress : "+www.progress);
    }
     Debug.Log("size : "+www.size);
     var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
     wwwForm.AddBinaryData("file", www.bytes, "Your_Video.mov","multipart/form-data");
     wwwForm.AddField("title", "Hello World");
     wwwForm.AddField("description", "How you doing?");

     FB.API("me/videos", HttpMethod.POST, UploadFinish, wwwForm);
 }

 private void UploadFinish(IGraphResult result) {
    Debug.Log("result : "+result.ToString()+" , error : "+result.Error);
 }
}
```

Thanks, Luke.

Good luck to everyone.