# How can I get upload speed while using facebook api to post videos

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I was trying to use facebook api to post a video to my time line, which works perfect, but the problem is I can only get a callback func when the upload is finished, and what I want is the upload speed, and a estimate time for a file to upload, I think this answer([a link][How to upload video with Facebook graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332197/how-to-upload-video-with-facebook-graph-api)) fits my question and I tried in my code, but what I get is the speed to load the local video file, not upload speed. So, is there any upload/download speed api that I can apply?

Comment: There is not such API. The most you could do, is implement resumable/chunked video upload - and then estimate the speed based on how long those chunks take to upload. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!